# After running some commands Front end css not working

Tags: magento2, css, frontend

Frontend CSS not working after I ran some commands.
Backend working fine all css and js files are working in backend
Here's [image]

Here's the link of the site:
http://testing2.dukaania.com

Comment: try running command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: already run that commanf

Comment: try to run command `rm -rf generated/* pub/static/*` and then run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the page source of your website in the browser. Then click on any included CSS or JS link.

You will find the error like the following:

```
ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\copy does not exist
```

If it is true, then the following solutions can help:

- First, check whether **`mod_rewrite`** module is enabled in the server.
- If yes, then check for 777 permission on **`var`**, **`pub`**, **`generated`**, and **`app/etc`** folders.
- If the above permission is fine, then run **`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`** from the terminal under document root folder.

Please let me know if the solution helps.